# How can I remove elements of vectors in a set of vectors?

Tags: c++, vector, set

If I have a set of unique vectors, how can I (for example) delete the second element in each vector?  I have created the following simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> myVec1 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    vector<int> myVec2 = {3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 1};
    vector<int> myVec3 = {2, 5, 3, 8, 6, 9};

    set<vector<int>> mySet;
    mySet.insert(myVec1);
    mySet.insert(myVec2);
    mySet.insert(myVec3);

    // right now this for loop deletes an element from a copy only
    for(auto item : mySet) item.erase(item.begin() + 2);

    for(auto item : mySet)
    {
        for(auto element : item) cout << " " << element;
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

This example can be [compiled and run on cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/64rz).

Possible solutions I have considered:

- Using `for(auto& item : mySet)`; however, this gives an error on compilation (no matching member function for call in const vector)
- Using an iterator ([gives a similar error](http://cpp.sh/9mjr))

Comment: `set` allows only a `const` view of its elements, because allowing you to mutate the elements can break the invariant of the data structure. Your options are 1) not using a `set` or 2) erase the entire `vector` from the `set`, and re-insert.

Comment: If I need to absolutely modify every element in the set would it be efficient to copy the entire set to a vector, modify each element, then re-insert?  That was my previous solution but it seems messy.

Comment: @brandaemon then it would be efficient to keep elements in a vector and (re)sort it when necessary. And it is strange that you are asking on efficiency, when you copy vectors just to print their content.

Comment: Why not use a list instead of a set? A set orders its members, which is why you cannot modify them like you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, the reason why I don't use more reasonable data types is what it usually is: project requirements.

Comment: Then only option you have to re-insert, as @T.C. mentioned before

Answer (score 1):

I would use `std::transform` to take the data from the existing set, modify as needed, and insert the results into a new set, then swap the old set with the new one:

```
std::set<std::vector<int> > mySet { 
    {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    {3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 1},
    {2, 5, 3, 8, 6, 9}
};

std::set<std::vector<int>> temp;

std::transform(mySet.begin(), mySet.end(), 
    std::inserter(temp, temp.end()), 
    [](std::vector<int> s) { s.erase(s.begin() + 1); return s; }
);

std::swap(temp, mySet);
```

If you're dealing with a lot of data, you might be better off getting a vector from the input set, erasing it from the input set, erasing the element from that vector, and inserting the result into the output.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the solution you're looking for, but you could have your set hold pointers to vectors instead.  This works for me:

```
int main() {

    vector<int> myVec1 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    vector<int> myVec2 = {3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 1};
    vector<int> myVec3 = {2, 5, 3, 8, 6, 9};

    set<vector<int>*> mySet;
    mySet.insert(&myVec1);
    mySet.insert(&myVec2);
    mySet.insert(&myVec3);

    for(vector<int>* item : mySet) item->erase(item->begin() + 2);

    for(vector<int>* item : mySet)
    {
        for(auto element : *item) cout << " " << element;
        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I admit, my definition of "works" is rather narrow, but how could sorting be preserved with the OP's code anyway?

Comment: it can be preserved by reinserting a vector after modification.

Comment: A set of pointers makes no sense.  As just a set of pointers, yeah the addresses are all different, so what?  But if you give it custom comparitors to dereference the vectors, you are just introducing a trick to allow yourself to introduce UB by having a set that is not correctly sorted.  And then if you drop this and go to the "modify and reinsert" approach, see my comment on that answer (possible false duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to remove the vector from the set of vectors before manipulating it and after the manipulation reinsert the vector.

Since this would involve a lot of creating/copying vectors, you could use pointers to vectors -- in which case you would need your own compare function object:

```
struct compare
{        bool operator()(
                 const std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int> > &_r0,
                 const std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int> > &_r1) const
         {        return *_r0 < *_r1;
         }
};
std::set<std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int> >, compare> sSet;
```

in order to delete the second element in each vector, I would first create a copy of all pointers:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int> > > sCopy(
        sSet.begin(),
        sSet.end());
sSet.clear();
for (auto p = sCopy.begin(), pEnd = sCopy.end();
        p != pEnd;
        ++p)
{        auto rVectorPtr = *p;
         if (rVectorPtr->size() > 1)
                 rVectorPtr->erase(rVectorPtr->begin() + 1);
         sSet.insert(rVectorPtr);
}
```

Comment: A reasonable design, but perhaps too tempting for someone to modify the vectors in place and break `set`'s invariant.

Comment: I think it should be `std::unique_ptr` instead of `std::shared_ptr` at least. With shared ownership in addiotion to problem, mentioned by @T.C. vector can be easily modified outside of `std::set`

Comment: @T.C. I was assuming that this code is not part of an interface but some implementation. If this is not the case, you might want to hide the functionality, which is not supposed to be accessed.

Comment: If you modify and reinsert in place, you are comparing the modified vector to other unmodified vectors.  You will be sorting it relative to things you don't want to sort, and you may eliminate duplicates that should not be eliminated.  Better to go with the Jerry Coffin answer, put all the modified vectors in a new set, and then swap sets.

Comment: Another point which I'm not sure about - how do you iterate over the set to do this?  Doesn't the re-insert invalidate the iterator?  I don't actually know, but I think it should.